# My requirement is to upload static xfa form,but it is not opening immediately

Tags: java

```
    try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);


            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            uploadedInputStream.close();

            resultfileData = dao.insertRecord(fileData);
            resultfileData.setStatus("success");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            resultfileData.setStatus("failure");
            throw e;
        }
    return resultfileData;
```

i am able to upload the file successfully.But when i try to open the file it shows the below message"There was an error opening this document.This file already open or in use by another application" please let me know is there any good approach to upload static Xfa form

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the stream `out` twice and the first one is not closed.

Try to remove row `out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));`. It is not necessary.

Comment: By removing the above line it is working perfectly.Thankyou so much for your answer.